# Does puppeteer headless chrome work in a Windows container in Azure App Service?

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, puppeteer, windows-container

**UPDATE**

As @Joaquín said, the base image was lacking dependencies. After a lot of research along with trial and error, I settled on using the heavy **servercore** image along with the necessary [fonts](https://github.com/prom3theu5/ServerCoreFonts/) required by Chrome. You can find my test app and Dockerfile on [my github](https://github.com/mbondarc/puppeteer-web-app).

I was able to get it running in Azure App Service as a Windows container, but the image is many times larger and much slower startup time than my Linux version. I'm still very new to Docker containers, so it's been interesting so far.

---

Running my puppeteer app in a Windows container in Azure App Services ends up with
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!`

Yet, it works flawlessly in a Linux container in Azure App Services. Do I have to do something particularly special to get it to work in a Windows container? Or is it futile due to the [sandboxing limitations](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/515) in a Windows app service (container or not)? Though, if this were the case, then I would've expected a `spawn UNKNOWN` error...

Some of the things I've tried included using the following puppeteer.launch() options:

1. `ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions']` (per [troubleshooting](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch-on-windows))
2. `executablePath: '<path_to_chromium>'`

Here's the error and stack trace

```
(node:1272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch chrome!


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (C:\app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:349:14)
    at Interface.helper.addEventListener (C:\app\node_modules\puppeteer\lib\Launcher.js:338:50)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at Interface.close (readline.js:397:8)
    at Socket.onend (readline.js:173:10)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1129:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
(node:1272) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1272) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Dockerfile

```
ARG core=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ARG target=mcr.microsoft.com/windows/nanoserver:1809
FROM $core as download

SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]

ENV NODE_VERSION 10.16.0

RUN Invoke-WebRequest $('https://nodejs.org/dist/v{0}/node-v{0}-win-x64.zip' -f $env:NODE_VERSION) -OutFile 'node.zip' -UseBasicParsing ; \
    Expand-Archive node.zip -DestinationPath C:\ ; \
    Rename-Item -Path $('C:\node-v{0}-win-x64' -f $env:NODE_VERSION) -NewName 'C:\nodejs'

FROM $target

COPY --from=download /nodejs/ /nodejs/

USER Administrator
RUN setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\nodejs"

RUN mkdir "C:\app"
WORKDIR "C:\app"

COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "node.exe", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: Hi, do you have your application and container up and running locally?  I tried to run your container but the NPM install is failing as it cannot find package.json and the the final line does not execute as there is no server.js in the container.  I also see no items in the c:\app folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it comes down to a Windows Containers, there is no limitation on the App Service sandbox since Hyper-V is being used as the sandbox for containers on App Service.

The only reason for the failure to launch chrome inside the container is that the base image of the Windows Container is missing some dependency that chrome needs.

If you share dockerfile, I would like to repro the issue.

Comment: I updated the OP with the dockerfile. Thanks for helping, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You were right, I had to use the full servercore image in order to get it to work. I updated the top of the OP with my findings. Thanks!